# Listing functions inside a script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wondering if there is already something to get a list of function's names inside a `script.py` file.

*Example:*

I have a `script.py` that has the following inside:

```
def func_1():
    message = 'Function 1'
    return message

def func_2():
    message = 'Function 2'
    return message

def func_3():
    message = 'Function 3'
    return message
```

And I want to write a function to get something like this:

```
functions = getAllFunctions('script.py')
functions = ['func_1', 'func_2', 'func_3'] # expected return value
```

I want to write that **`getAllfunctions()`** function.

Comment: Can you do `import script` or does it need to be from the string `'script.py'` ?

Comment: I has to be from the string 'script.py', I will parse all files with extensions (.py) inside a folder and then list the functions inside each file.

Comment: @derHund1877: Wasn't me who gave you link — was the three users that closed your question.